# Rails "google-search" gem not working with image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, rubygems

My "google-search" rails gem is not working with images.
when I run the gem with news, it populates the uri fine. but when i run the gem with Image. it returns nil. does anybody have any experience using this gem with images?

controller.rb

```
    class NewsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @results = Google::Search::Image.new(query: 'Cookies')
  end
end
```

html.erb file

```
<ul>

  <% @results.each do |result| %>
    <li>

      <%= result.uri %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

It works well when I replace the "Image" with "News"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/tj/google-search/issues/23).

Give [this gem](https://github.com/wiseleyb/google_custom_search_api) a try as an alternative